# Navigation Drawer List

Tags: android, dynamic, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer that use the below class to create the itens displayed:

```
public class Config {

public static List<NavItem> configuration() {

    List<NavItem> i = new ArrayList<NavItem>();

    //DONT MODIFY ABOVE THIS LINE

    //Some sample content is added below, please refer to your documentation for more information about configuring this file properly
    i.add(new NavItem("Bombeiro", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.SECTION));
    i.add(new NavItem("Home", R.drawable.ic_details, NavItem.ITEM, HomeFragment.class, null));
    i.add(new NavItem("Nova Vistoria", R.drawable.ic_vistoria_blue, NavItem.ITEM, VistoriaActivity.class));

    //It's suggested to not change the content below this line

    i.add(new NavItem("Opções", R.drawable.ic_action_settings, NavItem.SECTION));
    i.add(new NavItem("Importar dados", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.EXTRA, SyncImportFragment.class, null));
    i.add(new NavItem("Sincronizar Vistoria", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.EXTRA, SyncExportFragment.class, null));
    i.add(new NavItem("Salvar Vistoria", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.EXTRA, SaveFragment.class, null));

    //DONT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE

    return i;

}

}
```

I'm trying to change it to work dynamic. Thus, I tried to create a new file with other options, and call it; however, it did not change the list.

Could someone give me any tip?

Thank you

**EDIT**

This is the code used to get the list of itens:

```
private List<NavItem> getConfiguration(){
    if (null == mConfiguration){
        mConfiguration = Config.configuration();

        boolean newDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.newdrawer);

        if (newDrawer == true){
            mConfiguration.add(0, new NavItem("Header", NavItem.TOP));
        }
    }

    return mConfiguration;
}
```

I tried to make a setConfiguration like that:

```
private List<NavItem> setConfiguration(config){
    if (null != mConfiguration){
        mConfiguration = config.configuration();

        boolean newDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.newdrawer);

        if (newDrawer == true){
            mConfiguration.add(0, new NavItem("Header", NavItem.TOP));
        }
    }

    return mConfiguration;
}
```

And when, I clicked in a button, it calls.

Comment: can you share the code in which you try to change it

Comment: You probably need to re-create the menu in order for it to render the new items.

Comment: @YounasBangash I add the code, take a look!